# how to make heatmaps in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
[[ 0.09834044  0.05596437  0.08409548  0.01200539  0.05020909  0.05553221
   0.15732649  0.1705372   0.11046963  0.09910177  0.15449556  0.21226754
   0.13576098  0.2016396   0.17727435  0.1536272   0.19067327 -0.21381126
  -0.2876521  -0.6855868 ]
 [ 0.50199206  0.50393367  0.5068545   0.50819611  0.50898569  0.50882053
   0.50996339  0.51056341  0.51211042  0.51312654  0.51299576  0.51297555
   0.51485414  0.51529348  0.51537164  0.51642804  0.51767036  0.52046692
   0.52239931  0.52620384]
 [ 0.5366334   0.53374475  0.51116071  0.50105042  0.49343487  0.5074103
   0.49801061  0.49074439  0.490348    0.51273634  0.49330357  0.50341387
   0.51155462  0.5207458   0.50892857  0.5102416   0.49146534  0.4894958
   0.51825105  0.53006828]]
```

This is my dataset, but when I plot the heatmap then I get axis labels of yaxis from 0 to 20...and x labels 0 to 3.0. The heatmap colorbar has negative values.

```
plt.pcolor(dat3.T)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I have also tried plt.pcolor(dat3) with weird graph. Why is the data being interpolated in the final plot?

Comment: What makes you think the data is being interpolated?

Comment: the plot contains points above > 1.0 in labels, and if you look at the dataset all points are below 1.0

Comment: Your data has 3 rows and 20 columns.  What do the rows represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"heatmap" means many different things to many different people.  (For example, to me it means a kernel density estimate plot of some sort.)

From your description it sounds like you might have x, y, z data where you want to make a scatter plot of x and y, colored by z. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[ 0.09834044,  0.05596437,  0.08409548,  0.01200539,  0.05020909,
          0.05553221,  0.15732649,  0.1705372 ,  0.11046963,  0.09910177,
          0.15449556,  0.21226754,  0.13576098,  0.2016396 ,  0.17727435,
          0.1536272 ,  0.19067327, -0.21381126, -0.2876521 , -0.6855868 ],
        [ 0.50199206,  0.50393367,  0.5068545 ,  0.50819611,  0.50898569,
          0.50882053,  0.50996339,  0.51056341,  0.51211042,  0.51312654,
          0.51299576,  0.51297555,  0.51485414,  0.51529348,  0.51537164,
          0.51642804,  0.51767036,  0.52046692,  0.52239931,  0.52620384],
        [ 0.5366334 ,  0.53374475,  0.51116071,  0.50105042,  0.49343487,
          0.5074103 ,  0.49801061,  0.49074439,  0.490348  ,  0.51273634,
          0.49330357,  0.50341387,  0.51155462,  0.5207458 ,  0.50892857,
          0.5102416 ,  0.49146534,  0.4894958 ,  0.51825105,  0.53006828]]

x, y, z = data
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=120) # s=120 implies a marker size of 12 points.
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data ranges from -0.7ish to +0.5ish: that is why the colorbar has negative values.  You have three sets of data which appear on the plot as *bands* that are colored consistent with the colorbar.

```
>>> dat3.shape
(3, 20)
>>>
```

Transposing the data will plot the *datasets* as vertical columns next to each other.